# Where in Edinburgh can I shop for outdoor gear?

Tags: shopping, edinburgh

I'm going for a first time sailing trip next week on the Scottish West Coast and the Hebrides. I assumed nice weather this time of the year, but it turns out to be raining the entire time next week.

I will not have time to go shopping before my flight leaves, but I have some time in Edinburgh before I leave for Oban. So I thought to go shopping there.

One finds all sorts of online shops on the web, but my searches for actual walk-in shops for outoor clothing turned out to be futile. So I wondered if any of you had a tip for me.

Comment: " I assumed nice weather this time of the year, but it turns out to be raining the entire time next week" You've obviously never been before, that qualifies as good weather there (lived there for 39 years)

Comment: "but it turns out to be raining the entire time next week" surely not ?!  :)

Comment: Remember that sailing In The Real Ocean (is, Scotland), is not like pouncing around the greek Islands or the like.  Even if conditions are apparently good, adopt a seamanlike attitude, and come home alive!

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you search for:
  - [Chandlers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chandlers%20edinburgh) for sailing shops
  - [Camping](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=camping%20store%20edinburgh) stores
  - [Outdoor](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=outdoor%20store%20edinburgh) stores

All of those bring up several results with Edinburgh addresses. There is also a [Decathlon](http://www.decathlon.co.uk/) in Edinburgh.

You can search on google, or [google maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/outdoor+clothing+and+equipment+shop/@55.9485944,-3.2086683,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!2m7!3m6!1soutdoor+clothing+and+equipment+shop!2sEdinburgh+Castle,+Castlehill,+Edinburgh+EH1+2NG!3s0x4887c79a2099c0f7:0x469a1eebe54c0a58!4m2!1d-3.1999135!2d55.9485947).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I used to live in Edinburgh, and can thoroughly recommend [Tiso](http://www.tiso.com/shops/edinburgh-outdoor-experience).

Comment: Excellent real-world advice, cool